# How to get last page url in twilio pagination php

Tags: php, laravel, twilio, twilio-php

```
$page = isset($input['page'])?$input['page']:0;
$perPageRecord = 10;
$calls = $this->twilio->calls->page(["to" => "+919876543210"],$perPageRecord,'',$page);
$data = [];
echo $calls->getNextPageUrl; 
exit;
```

I am using above code to get next page url and it print successfully. But i want to print last page url while In php twilio. 
Anyone can tell me how can i get last page url using twilio php. 
Thanks

Comment: code formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you will need to programmatically extract a returned range and manipulate the resulting data to get the X most recent results (last page).

[Replacing Absolute Paging and Related Properties](https://www.twilio.com/blog/replacing-absolute-paging-and-related-properties)

[Usage and Migration Guide for Twilio's PHP Helper Library 5.x](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/php/usage-guide)